# Jenkins start failed

Tags: jenkins, redhat

I already installed java 11 and then I tried to start jenkins but always failed

```
-- Unit jenkins.service has begun starting up.
                  Running from: /usr/share/java/jenkins.war
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile
                  at java.base/sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getTimeZone(ZoneInfo.java:588)
                  at java.base/java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:577)
                  at java.base/java.util.TimeZone.setDefaultZone(TimeZone.java:682)
                  at java.base/java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultRef(TimeZone.java:653)
                  at java.base/java.util.TimeZone.getDefault(TimeZone.java:642)
                  at java.base/java.util.Calendar.defaultTimeZone(Calendar.java:1679)
                  at java.base/java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1660)
                  at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initializeCalendar(SimpleDateFormat.java:676)
                  at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:620)
                  at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:599)
                  at io.jenkins.lib.support_log_formatter.SupportLogFormatter.lambda$static$0(SupportLogFormatter.java:47)
                  at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:305)
                  at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:195)
                  at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:172)
                  at io.jenkins.lib.support_log_formatter.SupportLogFormatter.formatTime(SupportLogFormatter.java:53)
                  at io.jenkins.lib.support_log_formatter.SupportLogFormatter.format(SupportLogFormatter.java:63)
                  at java.logging/java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:199)
                  at java.logging/java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:95)

start jenkins success
```

Comment: Please some help me with this error on redhat 8

Comment: How did you install Jenkins? Via package manager? What Jenkins version are you trying to launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are missing TimeZone dependency. Check if file $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/tzdb.dat is pointing to empty or not existing file.
If so, install `tzdata-java` package. `yum install tzdata-java` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late comment. It solved my problem.